# Want to refresh page with updated SQL statement after choosing from dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, jquery, sql, ajax

I've tried to google A LOT, and searched in other stackoverflow similar post, but i can't really find something that's helping me -.-

I'm trying to make my site refresh and update my tables values, and only show the ones where it's equal to the dropdown menu.
When i enter the page i want it to show everything like it does now, and then update the site and my SQL statement, when choosing CustomerCountryCode
[I only want to show the 'DK', when choosing from the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMycf.png)

[Menu shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVINm.png)

> History.php (the WHERE should be something like $_POST['SelectedValue'] instead of 'DK')

```
if (isset($_POST['SelectedValue'])) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [CampaignModule].[dbo].[RetailCampaign] WHERE CampaignNo <> '' AND 
CustomerCountryCode like 'DK' ORDER BY ID DESC"
}else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [CampaignModule].[dbo].[RetailCampaign] WHERE 
CampaignNo <> '' ORDER BY 
ID DESC";
}

$sqlFilter = "SELECT DISTINCT CustomerCountryCode FROM [CampaignModule]. 
[dbo].[RetailCampaign]";
$params = array();
$options =  array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlColumns, $params, $options);
$stmtFilter = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlFilter, $params, $options);

echo '<select name="Filter" id="FilterSelect" class="form-control">
<option>Choose Country Filter</option>';
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtFilter, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

> HistoryControl.js - I tried to create a post function to insert the data, and reload the page when the menu is updated - I tried af few other things.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#FilterSelect").change(function () {
var value = $("#FilterSelect").val();
$.ajax({
  url: "../Model/History.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { 'SelectedValue=': value },
  success: function () {
      location.reload();
  }
});
});
});
```

Any form for optimization and other 'best practices' is much appreciated as well.
if more information or code needed tell me please

***UPDATE - SOLUTION***

With help and ideas from @Lam Tran Duc & @Manashree Shah

> History.php

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['SelectedValue'])) {
 $_POST['SelectedValue'] = $_SESSION['SelectedValue'];
 }

if (isset($_POST['SelectedValue'])) {
$_SESSION['SelectedValue'] = $_POST['SelectedValue'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM [CampaignModule].[dbo].[RetailCampaign] WHERE 
CampaignNo <> '' 
AND CustomerCountryCode='" . $_POST["SelectedValue"] . "'";
} else {
unset($_SESSION['SelectedValue']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [CampaignModule].[dbo].[RetailCampaign] WHERE 
CampaignNo <> '' 
ORDER BY ID DESC";
}
```

> HistoryControl.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#FilterSelect").change(function () {
var value = $("#FilterSelect").val();
$.ajax({
  url: "../Model/History.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { SelectedValue: value }, // remove the '=' character
  success: function (data) {
    //alert(data)
    location.reload();
  }
});
});
});
```

When i was doing this it's working, but i needed it to clear the $_SESSION variable which i had a lot of trouble with, and ended up with the solution to clear the session in me historyPage.php

```
<?php
include "../Model/History.php";
session_unset();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you are experiencing:

- Drop-down list (Country filter)
- A data display table.

When a value is selected in the drop-down list, the data in the table is filtered by the value of the selected drop-down list.

If I have understood correctly then I have a few ideas for you as follows:

**History.php**

I see it has 2 separate parts that have nothing to do with it:

- In the first `if / else` , you rely on the $_POST['SelectedValue']
  variable to define a query that gets the data displayed on the table.
- The rest of the code is used to get the data for the dropdown. I
  think this code should be in another file.

**HistoryControl.js**

I think this code is not very correct: `data: {'SelectedValue =': value}`. Since when you assign data like that when ajax calls History.php file, variable name will be `$_POST['SelectedValue=']` so in `if (isset($_POST['SelectedValue']))` will always return false . This leads to an unexpected result.

Edit it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../Model/History.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'SelectedValue': value }, // remove the '=' character
    success: function () {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: You understood the question correctly, and helped a lot!
- I posted an updated working version
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @BjarkeSkriverVilladsen I have seen the code you updated. I think you don't need PHP session. Here is my suggestion, you can try following this [link](https://github.com/lam-TD/stackoverflow/blob/master/want-to-refresh-page-with-updated-sql-statement-after-choosing-from-dropdown-menu/index.php).

Comment: thanks buddy! i've been looking through your code, and i got some pretty good ideas!

Answer (score 0):

How about you use PHP session variable like below:

```
if (isset($_POST['SelectedValue'])) {
  $_SESSION['SelectedValue'] = $_POST['SelectedValue'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM [CampaignModule].[dbo].[RetailCampaign] WHERE CampaignNo <> '' AND 
CustomerCountryCode like 'DK' ORDER BY ID DESC"
}else {
  $_SESSION['SelectedValue'] = "";
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM [CampaignModule].[dbo].[RetailCampaign] WHERE 
CampaignNo <> '' ORDER BY 
ID DESC";
}
```

and then you can use the session variable to preselect the option:

```
echo '<select name="Filter" id="FilterSelect" class="form-control">
<option>Choose Country Filter</option>';
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtFilter, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
  if($row[0] == $_SESSION['SelectedValue']){
   echo "<option value='$row[0]' selected>$row[0]</option>";
  }else{
   echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
  }
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: This is a way that i haven't thought about - In my first try it doesn't seems to work, but i will definitely try some more!
Anyway thanks!